# Run Google Directions API for traffic duration on fixed roads online and save data to a database?

Tags: android, python, directions

DISCLAIMER: Now this is an android application, but I imagine this aspect would require something like python.

I'm writing an application where I want to get duration due to traffic from fixed points on a map for certain high traffic areas. So far I can parse the JSON data and get the information I need quite nicely. This is fine for one user. However, if many people use the app, it becomes costly.

I want to "Script" (for lack of a better verb) a request with the fixed route to the `Directions` API every 20-30 min and have it update the online database.

Instead of having each user pull a request to the `Directions` API, I want to update the traffic data on certain roads/routes (known and fixed) on a database. Then the users read it from the database on the android application.

WHY: There is no user input in this scenario and hence this is a good way to reduce billing requests significantly.

Comment: A few comments: 1) I don't see why you would need Python. Just get the data and store it somewhere, perhaps Firebase. Java works for that. 2) I haven't checked the Directions API, but some APIs might not allow caching of data. 3) What is your exact and specific programming question that fits the StackOverflow format? Now this is just a rough idea.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I did some looking around I think running code in Firebase can do it. I was initially asking if anyone can recommend the simplest way to parse JSON files on a server (as a HTTP Request?) that then updates a (Firebase) database. Im fairly new to using JSON's / parsing, but i think Im on the right track to figuring it out. Maybe this question needs to be removed.